# No module named 'stocker'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble getting one line of code to run!

```
from stocker import Stocker
```

I keep getting this:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stocker'
```

I tried `pip install stocker` and `pip install Stocker`.  All I see is...'could not find version that satisfies the requirement'.  I'm on Python 3.7.  Any idea how to make this work?  Thanks to all.

Comment: Which python package refers to stocker? Is it this? https://github.com/WillKoehrsen/Data-Analysis/tree/master/stocker

Comment: Yes, yes, that's exactly what I was looking at.  Is there a special way to install this package?  I didn't see anything unusual with this one.  I've seen others that required special handling, especially on a Windows machine.

Comment: Go through the readme, seems like there is not setup.py as well for it, so maybe you would need to create one for it and use python setup.py install

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is not available in pip, you can check with 'pip search stocker' you have to download from github then import from the same folder you download to.

Comment: How do you do that, Flint?  I forked the whole folder on GitHub to my local folder and tried to install it, but there is no setup file to run.

Comment: no need to install, just switch to stocker folder, run python3 and do 'from stocker import Stocker'.  make sure the required packages are installed that are listed in github.

Comment: *this is not available in pip* - [stocker · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/stocker/)?

Answer (score 0):

change your python version to 3.6 and then run pip install stocker in your anaconda prompt terminal.